# Did the Mega Drive and/or Arcade version of the song "Afterburner" use FM synthesis or samples?

Tags: z80, sega-genesis

Does anyone know if the Mega Drive or Arcade version of Afterburner use FM synthesis or sound samples for orchestra hit in its song "Afterburner". I find oscilloscope views of each version but I'm not certain if I understand the wave forms in each video:

Here is [an oscilloscope view of the Mega Drive version](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A--I2jiobh8&t=9m50s) (looks like it uses FM synthesis, see second square from left, bottom row).

Here is [an oscilloscope of the Arcade version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zD4tzDi-F9M&t=0m10s) (looks like it uses sampled sounds, see two middle row, left side).

Any person program music for this game or disassemble its ROM probably know.

Comment: The description in the linked Mega Drive video describes the drums as being samples played via the SN76489 (/‘PSG’); not sure about the arcade.

Comment: Watching a walkthrough video, there are samples being played simultaneous with action on the screen, so it seems technically possible for the orchestra hits to also be samples. Probably the easiest way to know for sure is to disable the FM synthesis chip (the real one on actual HW or the emulated one in MAME) and listen to hear if the sound is still played.